# how to get the parameter in the remote modal, if the parameters are transfered by URl

Tags: html, url, modal-dialog, parameter-passing, bootstrap-modal

```
<button id="btn_modal" type="button" class="btn btn-default"
            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#receiptModal" onclick="showModal();">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>clike on me?
        </button>

js:
$("#myModal").modal({
            remote : "s.html?id="+100
        });
```

if I pass Id to s.html in a modal, how can I get the Id value?
Actually I can't get the whole URL, I just can get the parents' page Url.

Now I am trying to use Ajax to pass the parameters. like this below:
js:

```
showModal = function() {
    var selRow = $('#tb_materials').bootstrapTable('getSelections');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data : {
                id : selRow[0].id
            },
            url : 's.html',
            success : function(data) {
                $('#receiptModal').show();
                $('#modalContent').show().html(data);
            },
            error : function() {
                console.log("There is an Error ....!");
            }

        });

    };
```

But I still don't know how to get the parameters in s.html . Could someone can give me an example?

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use bootstrap 3.3.7